# Insert Picture from Cell in Sheet Header Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet named "sht__Infos". That sheet has a cell named "Cel__Logo". That cell contains a picture using the insert picture method. How can I link the picture in that cell to the Header Left Section so that if the picture is changed, It auto updates. And/Or it changes in the Activesheet.

The code I am using for entering the image in a named cell `cel__Logo` is

```
' Center_Resize_Image
Public Sub Center_Resize_Image()

On Error Resume Next
Dim result As Boolean
result = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show
On Error GoTo 0

If Not result Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim selectedShape As Shape
Set selectedShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)

 Dim widthInput As Variant
widthInput = InputBox("Enter width (default is 4.5cm):", , 4.5)

Dim heightInput As Variant
heightInput = InputBox("Enter height (default is 3cm):", , 3)

 Dim widthValue As Double
widthValue = IIf(IsNumeric(widthInput) And widthInput <> "", CDbl(widthInput), 4.5)

Dim heightValue As Double
heightValue = IIf(IsNumeric(heightInput) And heightInput <> "", CDbl(heightInput), 3)

selectedShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
selectedShape.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(heightValue)
selectedShape.Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(widthValue)

Dim myActiveCell As Range
Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell

With selectedShape
    .Top = myActiveCell.Top + (myActiveCell.Height - .Height) / 2
    .Left = myActiveCell.Left + (myActiveCell.Width - .Width) / 2
End With

myActiveCell.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: How the respective cell **contains** a picture? If you placed it inside of a cell, this does not mean that the respective cell contains it...  Then, there is no event able to determine the **when a picture is changed**. If the mentioned "insert picture" is programmatically done, I can show you a way to change the header picture when "Cel__Logo" value is changed. I mean, the procedure inserting/changing the picture **must write the picture full path in "Cel__Logo"**. Would it be convenient?

Comment: @FaneDuru. I am afraid it is being inserted via the insert image dialogue manually

Comment: Is it a problem to do it using a macro? The alternative would be you to write the new picture path, which is not so convenient, I would say. If the macro in discussion involves a dialog giving you the possibility to choose the file, **as you manually do it** would it be a problem?

Comment: @FaneDuru. See my edit

Comment: Yes, I will supply a little different equivalent macro and an event able to change the picture in the left header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please, copy the next code in a **standard module** and run it when need to change the picture (associate to a Form button, call the sub from an ActiveX button etc.)

```
Sub InsertPictureInCell()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, pictureFullPath As String, s As Shape, PictCell As Range
  Dim PWidth As Double, pHeight As Double
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set PictCell = sh.Range("Cel__Logo")
  
  'browse for the necessary picture:
  pictureFullPath = PictFilePicker
  
  'identify the picture to be replaced:
  'it must be inside the PictCell (with all its shape)
  For Each s In sh.Shapes
    If s.TopLeftCell = PictCell.left Then
        'PWidth = s.width: pHeight = s.height
        s.Delete: Exit For
    End If
  Next s
  PictCell.value = pictureFullPath 'write the path in the necessary cell
  
  With sh.Pictures.insert(pictureFullPath) 'place the picture inside the necessary cell
    .width = PictCell.width - 2
    .height = PictCell.height - 2
    .top = PictCell.top
    .left = PictCell.left
 End With
End Sub

Private Function PictFilePicker() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a picture to be inserted in the active sheet/leftHeader..."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Picture Files", "*.jpg, *.png, *.bmp"
        .Show
    
        If .SelectedItems.count > 0 Then
           PictFilePicker = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

In order to delete the previous picture, **that picture top left corner must be inside "Cel__Logo". Otherwise, it will not be deleted. Even if the newly inserted picture will be placed in the left header...

2. Copy the next code in the **sheet where you have "Cel__Logo" code module**. It is an event which will be triggered when the picture full name of "Cel__Logo" will be changed:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = Me.Range("Cel__Logo").Address Then
    Dim ImagePath As String, pict As Object, s As Shape
    ImagePath = Target.Value

    With Me.PageSetup
       Set pict = .LeftHeaderPicture
       With pict
           .Filename = ImagePath
              .LockAspectRatio = True
          .Width = Target.Width
       End With
    
       .LeftHeader = "&G" 'to make it visible...
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

You can play with the picture dimensions, to match your needs.

Now, play with inserting code and see the result in the left header.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: A true charm. Thank you